# How do I make Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision only ignore physical hard collisions and not trigger collisions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I just discovered how to ignore collisions and it's really helpful. I want it because I want some treasure in my game to both have a physical hard collider, and a trigger for when my player touches it. I don't want my player to collide physically with the treasure, but I do want my treasure to collide physically on the ground and not fall through.

Unfortunately when I used `Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision` it also ignores my Trigger collider that I use for when my player walks over the treasure to pick it up. I want the trigger collider to be enabled, and the physical hard collider to be disabled.

Here's my code:

```
public class colliderTreasureScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float jumpforce;
    public float speed;
    public LayerMask playerlayer; // 8
    public LayerMask treasurelayer; // 9
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(8, 9, true);
        Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(9, 8, true);
        Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(9, 9,true);
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpforce * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
```

Here's another script for picking up the treasure

```
public class GenericTreasureScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotatespeed;
    private Player playerscript;
    public int treasurevalue;
    public Transform movetowardsposition;
    public float speed;
    public bool touched;
   // public CircleCollider2D heavycollider;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        movetowardsposition = GameObject.Find("ScorePositionUpdated").transform;
        touched = false;
        playerscript = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
        //rotatespeed = Random.Range(140, 155.3f);
        speed = Random.Range(18, 22);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (touched == true)
        {

            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, movetowardsposition.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, movetowardsposition.position) < .2f)
        {
            destroy();
        }
}

 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {


            playerscript.score += treasurevalue;
            touched = true;
            StartCoroutine("destroyBackup");
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont want my player to collide physically with the treasure, but I
> do want my treasure to collide physically on the ground and not fall
> through

If you want to separate the physical and trigger collider to still trigger on player contact but not cause collision.

**You can either:**

1. Remove the [`RigidBody2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) completely, the object that gets triggered does not need a [`RigidBody2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) only the player would in your case and remove the physical collider
2. Keep the [`RigidBody2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) but set the [`gravityScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-gravityScale.html) to 0 and remove the physical collider
3. Add another extra layer and move the physical collider onto another parented game object with that layer for example `"treasurephysicallayer"`, then disable the collision only between that layer and the player instead of the layer were both colliders reside on

---

**Example Number 3:**

```cs
public LayerMask playerlayer; // 8
public LayerMask treasurelayer; // 9
public LayerMask treasurephysicallayer; // 10

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start() {
    Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(8, 8, true);
    Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(8, 10, true);
    Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(10, 8, true);
    Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(9, 9, true);
    Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(9, 10, true);
    Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(10, 9, true);
    Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(10, 10, true);
}
```

Additionally setting the layers via. code is possible, but setting them in the [`Physics2D PlayerSettings`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Physics2DManager.html) is much easier.

You can just tick off or on the corresponding collision you are currently setting via code.

[image: Collision Matrix]

Comment: I would just like to say you are an absolute genius! I can't believe I didn't think of that. I still want the Rigidbody and the collilder so I went with number three but I made the collider a childobject instead. Everything works great. You're an actual genius haha thank you so much!

Comment: @John why do you configure this via code at all and not simply in the [Physics2D Layer Collision Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Physics2DManager.html) ?